# NullPointerException when calling setOnClickListener for a button - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, location

I've started to learn Java and Android Development and as a first excercise I am trying to develop a Speedometer app for Android wich uses a custom Location Service, the problem seems to be that when I initialize the buttons in the OnCreate Method these cannot be found.

The app is based on the scroll template.

This is the OnCreate Method:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_speedometer);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


    speedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedText);
    unitText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unitText);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);


    if (!runtimePermissions()) //Will call a method that ckechs Location serivces are permited.
    {
        enableButtons();
    }
}
```

This is the eneableButtons() method that seems to cause the problem

```
 private void enableButtons() //using this method will not require the use of two buttons for On/Off
    {
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startClickCount++; //Counts how many time the button has been clicked
                if (startClickCount % 2 == 0) //If it is even
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPSService.class);
                    startService(i);

                }
                else
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPSService.class);
                    stopService(i);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

This is my fragment_speedometer.xml EDIT

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.amp.systems.performancespeedometer.Speedometer$PlaceholderFragment">


<Button
    android:text="Reset Info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="181dp"
    android:id="@+id/resetButton" />



<TextView
    android:text="999"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/speedText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Km/h"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/unitText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/speedText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
    android:id="@+id/startButton" />
```

And this is the Log I get when deployng:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.amp.systems.performancespeedometer, PID: 4090
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amp.systems.performancespeedometer/com.amp.systems.performancespeedometer.Speedometer}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at com.amp.systems.performancespeedometer.Speedometer.enableButtons(Speedometer.java:160)
                  at com.amp.systems.performancespeedometer.Speedometer.onCreate(Speedometer.java:154)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

The app just crashes when executed.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Could you post the full `activity_speedometer.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that `startButton` is null because it is not present in `activity_speedometer.xml`

Comment: I haven't seen activity_speedometer.xml before. The Project only opened speedometer_fragment.xml, but they seem the same, should I move the code from the fragment to activity.xml??

Comment: In this case you should be using onCreateView from your fragment class to bind the view with the event desired. You have to inflate your layout like this View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.speedometer_fragment.xml, container, false); . Then you can do this startButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startButton);

Comment: I'll try it now! Thanks

Comment: The inflater does not seem to be recognized and shows error

Comment: This inflater is given in your method onCreateView of your Fragment as an LayoutInflater type. The point is, you can bind your button either by onCreate from your activity (as long as this view is present in activity_speedometer.xml) or by using onCreateView (if you are using fragments). Have a look on this material https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: After Reading it I added the onCreateView method wich inflates the current fragment but as I am targeting Android  7.1.1 Speedometer extends AppCompactActivity not Fragment. Also in the activity_speedometer I cannot add any UI elements at all, only in fragment_speedometer so I changed the XML file in the `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_speedometer);`

Comment: I also seem to be getting an error in the `@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_speedometer, container, false);
    }`
The error is that the method is not overriding the method from it's super class

Answer (score 0):

Where is the xml where you declare the id for:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

I think you might be missing that id, or you have a different name for your id.

Greeting

Comment: I just uploaded It, it's activity_speedometer.xml